# Connecting to MySQL database with ASP on a virtualized Windows 2003 x64 server

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, vbscript, odbc, dsn

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL 5 database using the MySQL ODBC 5.1 driver. In the control panel's ODBC settings I created and tested the ODBC connection and it's working fine. When I try to use the connection from VBScript code I get an error though:

```
ADODB.Connection error '800a0ea9' Provider is not specified and there is no designated default provider.
```

I use the following code:

```
sConnection = "DSN=mydsn;"
Set objConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open(sConnection)
```

DSN-less (DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};) returns the same error.

Can you help me get this working, please?

Some things that might be the cause: The server is a Virtuozzo virtualized Windows 2003 server with IIS6 running as 64bit. I have installed the MyODBC 3.51 (x64) and MyODBC 5.1 (x86 and x64).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on running IIS in 64bit mode - I followed advice found on some message board to reconfigure IIS to run in 32bit mode. After that ODBC still does not work, but now I can atleast connect dsn-less...

Answer (score 1):

I found this to work from Windows to MySQL as a DSN-less connection.  The trick was to ELIMINATE  the port spec at the end of the server address.

"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 UNICODE Driver}; Server=**;Database=**;User=**;Password=**; OPTION=3"

Note: Server string is the internet address of the server, BUT NO PORT SPECIFIED - ie, NO ":3306" on the end

Answer (score -1):

You might try

```
Provider=MySQLProv;DSN=mydsn;
```

Comment: Nope, That just gives me: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.